# Adding If condition in Yaml pipeline for a copy task

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

In Azure Devops pipeline, I have a Copy task like below which copies the file in 3 different folder as it run for 3 different agent(MAC, LINUX and WINDOWS). I want the below Copy task to be run Only for windows . How can I do it as I don't want the below file in MAC and Linux Folder.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
          displayName: 'Copy ONNX to bin folder'
          inputs:
            SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/packages/ONNXRuntime/runtimes/win-x64/native'
            Contents: onnxruntime.dll
            TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ProjectName_x64-$(osSuffix)/bin'
            flattenFolders: true
```

Comment: Did you start by looking at the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `condition` parameter to drive the task at runtime:

```yaml
- task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy ONNX to bin folder'
    condition: $[eq(variables['osSuffix'], 'WINDOWS')]
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/packages/ONNXRuntime/runtimes/win-x64/native'
      Contents: onnxruntime.dll
      TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ProjectName_x64-$(osSuffix)/bin'
      flattenFolders: true
```